# Gitkraken having no permission create folder on Linux

Tags: linux, gitkraken

I am trying to clone a remote repo with Gitkraken on Linux.  The action failed due to having no permission to create new folder, though I was logged in as Admin.  Can someone please help?

Comment: Apparently, folders in Ubuntu require permission setting under Properties.  Once all are set correctly, SmartGit and GitKraken can work properly.

Answer (score 11):

Gitkraken runs as your user, make sure it has write permissions to the directory that will hold your repo.

```
sudo chown -R {username} /path/to/repo/
```

Answer (score 7):

If the permission error occurs with ubuntu software center / snap and trying to browse a mount, you can fix it -according to [this comment](https://github.com/mmtrt/gitkraken/issues/4#issuecomment-381175041)- like this:

```
sudo snap connect gitkraken:removable-media
```

*Edit: since the [old snap](https://github.com/mmtrt/gitkraken) was taken over by the core team, the plug "removable-media" has disappeared. This solution doesn't work for now. Core team told me this task is in their backlog.*

Comment: It doesn't work here:   


``error: snap "gitkraken" has no plug named "removable-media"``  

Ubuntu 18.10 / gitKraken 4.1.1

Answer (score 5):

Install `gitkraken` with with `devmode` (Using Linux snap) [Installing snap on Linux](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-linux-mint)

Remove old version ( Optional )

`sudo snap remove gitkraken`

Install gitkraken by following command

`sudo snap install --devmode gitkraken`

now you are ready to rock....

Answer (score 4):

For me downloading Gitkraken form their website instead of the Ubuntu software centre solved the issue. Like is described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52459027/4878398) answer.

Answer (score -1):

open with sudo user

> su

password:...

then

> gitkraken.